# Why responsive image doesn't work this way?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading, responsive-images

I am trying to figure out how responsive image syntax works with [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). It works.

**This way:**

```css
.border {
   border: solid 1px #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.2.2/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<picture>
    <source
        data-srcset="
            https://via.placeholder.com/150/150 1x,
            https://via.placeholder.com/300/150 2x,
            https://via.placeholder.com/450/150 3x
        "
        type="image/jpeg"
    >
    <img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        width="150"
        height="150"
        data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/150"
        alt="Test Image"
        class="lazyload border"
    >
</picture>
```

But doesn't work...

**This way:**

```css
.border {
   border: solid 1px #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.2.2/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<picture>
    <source
        data-srcset="
            https://via.placeholder.com/300/150 2x,
            https://via.placeholder.com/450/150 3x
        "
    >
    <img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        width="150"
        height="150"
        data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        alt="Test Image"
        class="lazyload border"
    >
</picture>
```

I just don't understand whats the point of repeating the **data-src** on the image if its already written once in **source element**.
I am not sure if snipped with show the problem you probably would have to paste data to HTML to test it on your browser.

Comment: Shouldn't height and width have a unit? Like `px` or `em` or whatever?

Comment: afaik it shouldn't

Comment: @EmilioGrisolía HTML width and height are in px.

Comment: Why use a library? `<img srcset />` is [natively supported in HTML5](https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/133-figuring-responsive-images/)

Comment: images must lazyload for performance reasons especially on mobile, i know that there is lazyliad attribute but Id rather have good compatibility

Comment: At this point, most browsers support native lazy loading....`loading="lazy"` or `"eager"`.

Comment: @Fongers Chrome, firefox yes, but safari and other browsers not so much. https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr 72.9%, not a good idea to loose 27.1% of browsers.